# Can the tick for "autofit column widths on update" be set to unticked by default

Tags: excel, pivot, settings, config, pivot-table

I would like to have the pivot tables options "autofit column widths on update" default to un-ticked.

Is there any way to do this?

[image: Image of pivotTable options box with autofit highlighted]

Comment: Thanks Pnuts, i'm looking for an option to have this as a default setting when ever I open Excel / make a new pivot, rather than code it every time I create a new sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time I create a pivot I do so using my Instant Pivot routine, that I've put in my personal workbook. It does exactly what you want and a heck of a lot more. Just assign it a keyboard shortcut like ctrl + shift + P and use that shortcut any time you want to create a pivot.  Much faster than doing it manually. See http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/02/12/instant-pivot-just-add-water/

Comment: Cool...glad you find it useful. It's my most heavily used macro